# Airflow - How to skip next day's instance?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, skip

I have a DAG 'abc' scheduled to run every day at 7 AM CST. For some reason, I do not want to run tomorrow's instance. How can I skip that particular instance. Is there any way to do that using command line ? Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can preemptively create a DAG Run for the future date at in the UI under Browse->DAG Run -> Create, initializing it in the success (or failed) state, which should prevent the scheduler from creating a new run when the time comes. I think you can do this on the CLI with [trigger_dag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli.html#trigger_dag) as well, but you'll just need to separately update its state cause it'll default to running.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will check that. I have one more question, related to Airflow Windows server. We use bash operator if we want to execute a Unix script in Unix server. Any idea about executing files in Windows server, which operator we can use to trigger a file on Windows server. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the start_date for the day after tomorrow or whatever date you want your dag run as long as it is in the future. but the schedule interval will stay the same every 7AM. You can start date in Default_Args

Answer (score 0):

You could create a *Start* Task as `ShortCircuitOperator` and if you want to skip the DAGs run - just return False from its `python_callable`. It will mark Task as `SKIPPED` and prevent the downstream tasks to run.

Benefits:

- you would explicitly see all skipped this way DAG runs in Tree View
- you will be able to check particular reason (if there could be several) in the logs
- user will be able to manually force a DagRun if required..

  ```
    def start_production(execution_date, ti) -> bool:
        return bool(<condition_whether_continue_DagRun>)

    with DAG('MyDag', ... ) as dag:
         ...

        start = ShortCircuitOperator(
                task_id='start',
                python_callable=start_production,
                op_kwargs=parameters,
                dag=dag
            )
            ...
            start >> [rest_of_dag_tasks]
  ```